# How to GET value in Community Builders field

Tags: php, joomla

How can I get a value from the site URL in the text box of Community Builders field?

Comment: Use `JFactory::getURI($url);`

Comment: ya i get the value by this but i want to fetch that value in text box of community builder'S FIELD(This is the problem .. I am unable to fetch in textbox on pageload.. USING COMMUNITY BUILDER) pLZ.. hELP..

Comment: It will be better if you can show us some code ...

Comment: `Not working properly` no one is god :) Need to elaborate your problem , to get some solution.

Comment: :'( i do not have manual code for my community builders problem because its a component.. and a want to insert value in the field of registration form of community builder..

Comment: In that case you have to tweak the code in your CB component core or have to create a plugin to achieve your need as if CB it self doesn't provide such functionality..

Comment: OK... I also Thinking The Same...

Comment: I tried to tweak before but unable to achieve the goal.. plugin creation  is the better  idea..

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. What do you mean "in text box of community builder's FIELD"?  Which screen, which module, which component? In the front end of Joomla or the administrator end?  Are you prepared to write PHP code, maybe even develop or modify a module, to get what you want?

Comment: didn't understand it also. Please elaborate.